# Relative path from the /usr/local/bin/ directory

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to place my "executable" python file in the /usr/local/bin/ directory so that I can call that program (superloop) anywhere in bash.

However, the rest of the applications is stored in another directory /root/superloop/

I have the **init**.py file in the /root/superloop and my relative import path in the file superloop under /usr/local/bin/ is this:

```
from ...root.superloop.auditdiff import auditdiff
```

This throws an error when I execute:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/superloop", line 3, in <module>
    from ...root.superloop.auditdiff import auditdiff
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Here is the tree:

```
|-- \\
|-- auditdiff.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- multithread.py
```

Comment: Have you considered using a symbolic link instead of moving your executable python file?

Answer (score 3):

As the error tells you, packages are not the same as directories; you cannot use relative imports to navigate the disk structure.

In order for your "executable" to find the packages in your `/root/superloop`, you can manipulate your [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to let your Python know where to look for your packages:

```
sys.path.append('/root/superloop')
from auditdiff import auditdiff
```

Comment: Do I have to 'import sys' first before 'sys.path.append('/root/superloop')'

Comment: Yes, indeed you do.